# Two array merge into a third array in c

Tags: arrays, c

For some Reason the Program Crashes at the Loop used to merge the two arrays in main.
though maybe this question is a foolish in one(idk it didn't allow me to post as my program is mostly code so now i am blabbering).
(Well it still doesn't so here's a Picture of a Cat
[CAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sxrv.jpg) )

```
 //To make two arrays of user Defined Size and merge them in a third array
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    void array(int**,int);
    void ini(int**,int);
    void display(int **,int);
    int main()
    {
        int *a1,*a2,*a3,s1,s2,i,j;
        printf("Enter Size of Array 1\n");
        scanf("%d",&s1);
        printf("Enter Size of Array 2\n");
        scanf("%d",&s2);
        ini(&a1,s1);
        ini(&a2,s2);
        ini(&a3,s1+s2);
        printf("Enter Elements of Array 1\n");
        array(&a1,s1);
        printf("Array 1:\n");
        display(&a1,s1);
        printf("Enter Elements of Array 2\n");
        array(&a2,s2);
        printf("Array 2:\n");
        display(&a2,s2);
        for(i=0;i<s1;i++)
        {
            a3[i]=a1[i];
        }
        for(i=0,j=s1;i<s2&&j<s1+s2;i++,j++)
        {
            a3[j]=a2[i];
        }
        printf("Merged Array:\n");
        display(&a3,s1+s2);
        return 0;
    }
    void ini(int **a,int s)
    {
        *a=(int*)calloc(s,sizeof(int));
    }
    void array(int **a,int s)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter Element at position %d\n",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
    }
    void display(int **a,int s)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            if(i==s-1)
            printf("%d\n",a[i]);
            else
            printf("%d\t",a[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run your code in a *debugger*. It will tell you near-immediate that the addressing model you're using in `array` is wrong. Fwiw, it's equally wrong in `display`. *Neither* function should require `a` be passed via double-indirection. [Enabling warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/ncKfd9cKG) and treating them as errors certainly wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: "It didn't allow me to post as my program is mostly code so now i am blabbering" You might instead add information about what input you provide to produce the crash. Or what you have done to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a1, a2, and a3 is a pointer of an integer type variable, which stores the starting address of your buffer.

a1[index] is the value in the address of a1 with 'index' as the offset.

Since you were passing `&a` to your `array()` and `display()` function, you were passing the address of your variable into the function instead of passing the address of your buffer.

You could change your `array()` and `display()` to:

```c
void array(int *a,int s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Element at position %d\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(a[i]));
    }
}
void display(int *a,int s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        if(i==s-1)
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        else
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
array(a1,s1);
display(a1,s1);
```